# Angular JS Promise only resolving in markup, not model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm having an issue resolving my promise—the strange this is that in my markup:

```
{{details.customer_email}}
```

It resolves **properly**, and displays the e-mail address returned by the '$http` request.

However, attempting to access this:

```
$scope.user = {
    ...
    emailAddress : $scope.details.customer_email,
    ...
};
```

is `null`.

Here's the relevant block:

```
$scope.session = {
    is_authenticated: false,
    customer_email: null
};

var detailsDeferred = $q.defer();

$scope.details = detailsDeferred.promise;

$scope.authed = function () {

    $http({
        url: 'http://api.foo/auth',
        withCredentials: true,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, xhr) {

            $scope.session = {
                is_authenticated: data.is_authenticated,
                customer_email: data.customer_email
            };

            detailsDeferred.resolve($scope.session);


        })
        ...

    return $scope.session;

};

$scope.authed();

$scope.user = {
    ...
    emailAddress: $scope.session.customer_email
        ...
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working in your markup is because angular's template engine is "promise aware", it's very convenient.

Quoted from the [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q):

> $q promises are recognized by the templating engine in angular, which means that in templates you can treat promises attached to a scope as if they were the resulting values.

In your JavaScript code, however, you have to handle it all by yourself:

```
$scope.user = {
    ...
    emailAddress : null,
    ...
};

$scope.details.then(function(details) {
    $scope.user.emailAddress = details.customer_email;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Worth noting that I had to redefine the *entirety* of the `$scope.user` object inside the `then()` in order to get it to work. Not sure why that is...

Comment: You might want to use defer/promise in your `$scope.user` as well, my 2 cents.

Comment: Update your question with your progress and new issues.